# Xcode beta 7.0 Cannot link to unwind segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am running through the Swift tutorial using the FoodTracker application.  I am at the step of "Implement Navigation" under "Working with Table Views."  I am stuck at the step where I need to control-drag my save button into the Exit button of the MealViewController modal popup.  The storyboard UI will simply not let me drag onto the Exit button.  I have researched quite a bit online, and all signs point to my unwind function that exists in MealTableViewController.swift.  It is suggested that my function signature is not correct.  However, I have quadruple verified that it is correct and in the right spot.  In fact, I downloaded the sample project from the end of the step, and copied/pasted the entire MealTableViewController.  I am still unable to link to the Exit button using control-drag.  It works fine in the downloaded example, but not in mine.  At this point, I'm in the middle of doing DIFFs on every file in my project compared to the downloaded one.  So far, all is the same!

Am I missing something that is required for this to be enabled?

also, one more thing that I already double checked, is to make sure that the modal source view is properly linked to the MealTableViewController class.

Here is my code in MealTableViewController.swift that is linked to the view that is CALLING the modal popup

```
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? MealViewController, meal = sourceViewController.meal {
        // Add a new meal item.
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: meals.count, inSection: 0)
        meals.append(meal)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
    }
}
```

(using Xcode version 7.0 beta 7A121I)
this is the tutorial page I am on:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

1. Ctrl-click the "exit" button once.
2. On the menu that appeared drag the empty dot (next to "unwindToMealList") to Save button and select "action".

I also had to:

1. Ctrl-click the "Save"
2. Drag referencing outlet to saveButton

You can download the project at the end of the lesson and just ctrl-click "Exit" or "Save" button and compare it with your project!

Edit note: First disconnect any connections.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  This was over a year ago, but I did compare the final project to my own, and they looked identical.  Your answer may fix the problem, but I gave up on Xcode and Swift, and successfully built and launched my first App Store app via Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found this issue and unfortunately have not found a resolution. I do wonder if this is a bug with the latest Xcode (6.4).

In the end I just coded a dismiss segue instead of unwind, and linked this to a button IBAction:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Not saying this 'answers' your question, but at least gives an alternate method and may avoid you wasting time looking for an elusive answer.